# Need help with realtek wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, compiling, 21.10

This is my first hand experience with Linux so I'm not really sure what has gone wrong. While installing Realtek WiFi adapter I am getting the following error it is a RTL8188EUS chipset which came with a CD [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkvW5.png)

```
chmod +x install.sh 
sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for roseblade: 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222.tar.gz
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/runwpa
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_bt_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wapi.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_tdls.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wapi_sms4.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_sreset.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ap.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_led.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/wlan0dhcp
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/pci_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/custom_gpio_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/gspi_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/sdio_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/gspi_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/sdio_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/hal_com.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/wifi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/custom_gpio.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/HalPwrSeqCmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_pg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_gspi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_recv.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_ce_service.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/HalVerDef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ethernet.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723APhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723APhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_ops_linux.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723PwrSeq.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/wireless.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_bt_mp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_tdls.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ap.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_wapi.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/hal_intf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sta_info.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_spec.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8188EPwrSeq.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/autoconf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/basic_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/ip.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/if_ether.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_bt-coexist.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_sdio.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_led.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/Makefile
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/Kconfig
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_types.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11N.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_precomp.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EReg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_BB.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RTL8188E.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188ERateAdaptive.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_RF.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_RF.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_FW.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalPhyRf_8188e.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RegConfig8188E.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RTL8188E.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_BB.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_FW.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RegConfig8188E.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188ERateAdaptive.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalPhyRf_8188e.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_reg.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11AC.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.h
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_intf.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_sreset.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rxdesc.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_cmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rf6052.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/Hal8188EPwrSeq.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_mp.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_phycfg.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_dm.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_led.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_recv.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_hal_init.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_xmit.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_com.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/clean
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
bash: line 1: make: command not found
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
bash: line 1: make: command not found
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 127
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

My Ubuntu version is 21.10.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? That driver is probably too old for current Ubuntu. You can find an answer how to install a driver for this device.

Comment: Novembor, 21 2011 ??? I'm somewhat not surprised this isn't working. Can you include in your post what version of Ubuntu you're using? And also maybe explain why you're running a script for a 10 year old driver? That would be a good start. 

Comment: Please, read previous comments. If you are really sure to mess up your system, run the command `sudo apt install make` to install the missing `make` command.

Comment: i'm using the latest ubuntu (non LTS one) also i have two wifi adapters one has a printed antenna (which yeilds slow speeds) and another one with an antenna which gives insane amounts of speed 3-5mbps the other one works with any kind of driver and doesn't need any special driver or driver update but the antenna one doesn't plug & play so to use that i copied the files from the CD i got with the wifi adapter.

Comment: I'm sorry I need to understand something, to check we're in the same universe: Are you saying that a over 10 year old WiFi adapter is giving insane amount of speeds at 3-5mpbs? 

Comment: yes since it has a large antenna while the other one is a simple printed board size of a coin also i did what FedKAd told me to ```sudo apt install make``` it went good for a while but then i got this

Comment: /home/roseblade/Documents/linux/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h:957:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  957 |         init_timer(ptimer);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
      |         _init_timer
In file included from /home/roseblade/Documents/linux/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:
/home/roseblade/Documents/linux/RTL8188EU................ cannot fit in comment

Comment: it is a RTL8188EUS chipset

Comment: Okay, sorry for not being specific havent used a computer for decades.

Comment: Yes that explains a thing or two.. I would strongly advice against using this old adapter, and instead use a more modern one. I believe it will be way too difficult and insecure to get this working. I'm sorry, that's the best advice I can give.

Comment: thank you for your advice and time since even i thought the same might get a modern one when i can afford it!

Comment: This adapter should work. Connect to the internet with yourphone USb cable, install `build-essential` and then install a driver from git.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: You must have a temporary internet connection to download drivers. You can use ethernet, USB tethering with your phone.

You are following the wrong instructions! Here are the correct steps:

First, open a terminal by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> .

Then run the following commands to install the drivers:

```
cd $HOME
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu.git
cd ~/rtl8188fu
make 
sudo make install
```

If you are getting errors while running `make` or `make install` then run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libelf-dev
cd ~/rtl8188fu
make clean
cd $HOME
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the technically correct solution. However, for usability and security, I still believe the best solution is to get a newer WiFi adapter. 

Comment: `build-essential` is needed too.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, you're correct. Thanks. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Also a temporary network connection is needed.